# Fill select box with wordpress child pages

Tags: wordpress

I use the function to populate a select box with the child pages of a given page.

```
    function countries_select( $atts )
    {

        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'page',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_parent'    => 10490,
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
         );

        $parent = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $parent->have_posts() ) 
        {

            $option_return = '<select id="baw_jumpposts"><option selected="selected">Select</option>';

            while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();
                $option_return .= '<option value="'.the_ID().'">'.the_title().'</option>';
            endwhile;
        }
        $option_return .= '</select>';

        return $option_return;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'select_1', 'countries_select' );
```

It is generating the select box with the empty options, and it is displaying the ID and TITLE of the pages outside the select box
The code is in the functions.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions [the_ID()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) and [the_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) display (echo) their values when called.

You need to use the functions [get_the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/) and [get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) instead as these **return** the values instead of displaying them so you can use them in your PHP code.